# virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference while login with facebook android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, facebook-login

give me virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference runtime error while login in with facebook in android firebase app

Login activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText log_email, log_password;
private TextView new_account;
private Button google_signin, sign_up_phone,login;
private LoginButton facebook_login;
private String memail,mcurrentUserID,mpassword;

LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 234;
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

private static final String TAG = "signup";

GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

FirebaseAuth mAuth;

CallbackManager callbackManager;

private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    log_email = findViewById(R.id.log_email);
    log_password = findViewById(R.id.log_pass);
    new_account = findViewById(R.id.new_account);
    login = findViewById(R.id.login);
    sign_up_phone = findViewById(R.id.sign_up_phone);
    facebook_login = findViewById(R.id.login_button);



   // printkey();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    facebook_login.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");


    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);


    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                loginuser();
        }
    });

    new_account.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent phoneLoginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(phoneLoginIntent);
        }
    });

    sign_up_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent phoneLoginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, phoneloginActivity.class);
            startActivity(phoneLoginIntent);
        }
    });

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    findViewById(R.id.google_sign).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signInWithGoogle();
        }
    });

    facebook_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            facebooklogin();
        }
    });
}


private void loginuser()
{
    memail  = log_email.getText().toString();
     mpassword = log_password.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(memail))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mpassword))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        loadingBar.setTitle("Sign In");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait....");
        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        loadingBar.show();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(memail, mpassword)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            mcurrentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                            Intent phoneLoginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(phoneLoginIntent);
                            finish();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in Successful...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error : " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    //if the requestCode is the Google Sign In code that we defined at starting
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

        //Getting the GoogleSignIn Task
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            //Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

            //authenticating with firebase
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}


private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    //getting the auth credential
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

    //Now using firebase we are signing in the user here
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User Signed In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}

private void signInWithGoogle()
{
    //getting the google signin intent
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();

    //starting the activity for result
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


private void facebooklogin()
{
    facebook_login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            handlerFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            // ...
        }
    });
}

private void handlerFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken)
{
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        FirebaseUser my = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                       // String email = my.getEmail();
                      //  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"you are login with "+email,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });
}


}
```

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".UI.LoginActivity"></activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>




    <activity android:name=".UI.phoneloginActivity" />
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBmO98uCPTg3R6yfOBXS8A6WuxK5c_aAzo" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".UI.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    <activity android:name=".UI.SignUpActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

i put facebook app id in manifest give haskey in facebook developer,enable facebook auth. give app id and give app secret key, and also put oAuth redirect uri in facebook developer but still show me this error while loginactivity open

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.geofensenearbyuser, PID: 9373
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.geofensenearbyuser/com.example.geofensenearbyuser.UI.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Please post your error log

Comment: okay i will put it

Comment: can you share your layout file too?

Comment: i sloved it,but thanks for your time and help

Comment: Good. Then post your solution here. So if other will get the same issue, this will help them.